# ASP.Net - Entity Framework - Applicatiopn slows down after inactivity

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am building an application in ASP.Net C# using Entity Framework.
I have deployed it on IIS7.5

When I restart the IIS, first time it takes quite some time to display login page ( i consider it warm up time .. am i right? ). Then it starts working as normal. But if I leave the application opened for another 10 to 15 minutes without doing anything, and then I use, it behaves in same way. It takes too much time ( around 15 to 20 seconds ) to refresh the page which next time takes only few seconds.

What could be cause of it it?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the Application on IIS timing out when there is no activity, and then having to restart when there is activity.  Take a look at the Application and Session time out properties in IIS.

Comment: Session timeout is 20 minutes, and it goes to this idle state before 20 minutes. Secondly I remain logged in when I use application after some time. So this means I was not logged out due to session timeout.

Is it something to do with entity framework?